# cookies dont work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am using a simple javascript code like this to play around with cookies

```
var theCookie = "login = ScottPilgrimVStheWorld";

document.cookie=theCookie;
alert(document.cookie);
```

I have just a simple `html` page with a body, a header and this javascript code.

Problem is , this is working in IE and FF but not in GC 33.0.1750.154 m. I get an empty alert box. I took a glance at the GC settings and found nothing on blocking/unblocking Cookies. What is happening? Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here is another function for reading cookies

```
function getCookie(searchName)
{
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
var cookieCrumbs = cookies[i].split("=");
var cookieName = cookieCrumbs[0];
var cookieValue = cookieCrumbs[1];
if (cookieName == searchName)
{
return cookieValue;
}
}
return false;
}
```

"The JavaScript Anthology 101 Essential Tips, Tricks & Hacks" by James Edwards and Cameron Adams, Copyright © 2006 SitePoint Pty. Ltd., pp145-146

Comment: Can you create fiddle or a page to demonstrate? It seems to be working ok.

Comment: @D. Kasipovic Here is a fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/2/` . I edited the code based on the ansers here. This one does not even alert anything

Comment: Well, I see `login=ha` in the alert. You don't? BTW, you pasted your javascript in css. Paste it in bottom left box. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/kKfJK/4/

Comment: @D. Kasipovic Oups, wrong place! Yes I pasted js on the js and works. Still works only on the fiddle , not my site. I used chris97ong function and still not alert nothing on GC. I dont get it.

Comment: Well, if it works in fiddle it is valid js, so the error is probably somewhere else. We cannot really know that without seeing your code.

Comment: @D. Kasipovic My code is simply this `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/6/` . Nothing else. I am just playing with cookies and for some reason do not alert anything on GC. And dont get why.

Comment: Well it is alerting on the fiddle? As I said, if it works on the fiddle, the code is right, error is probably elsewhere.

Comment: @D. Kasipovic  I use Dreamweaver. Only when I set a website, cookies work fine in GC also. Now the url is `http://localhost/test/index.html`. Maybe has something to do with `Any scriptcan only read cookies that were set by a
web page from the same domain.`? Thanks anyway . Also check my question for another function of reading cookies.

Answer (score 1):

No spaces are allowed in the assignment string added to the cookie jar. Try

```
var theCookie = "login=ScottPilgrimVStheWorld";
```

Tested on chrome 33 ( 33.0.1750.154 ).

edit:
chris97ong is right in his claim that you need additional logic to extract a single cookie from the cookie jar `document.cookie`. if you need that, use his code or match against a regex:

```
var mycookie = document.cookie.replace(/(^|;)login=([^;]+)(;|$)/, "$2");
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/2/` . I edited the code based on the ansers here. This one does not even alert anything

Comment: if you enter your javascript in the proper widget of the jsfidddle ui (bottom left, named 'JavaScript') instead of the css field, it works like a charm ... !

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But, still does not alert anything on my site. Only works on fiddle. The code is simply this `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/6/` . I also used chris97ong's function above. Still nothing on GC. Alerts just an empty box. Cookies are enabled on GC. The site is localhost, url is `file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/test/index.html`. Beats me!

Comment: open the developer tools (ctrl+shift+j) and enter 'document.cookie' in the console. you will see the cookies stored for the page you are currently on. you may also try to enter your js code in the console. there might be a problem iwth cookies and file urls, i can upload a test page of yours to a web server if you wish to check this out and not have access to a web server.

Comment: I use Dreamweaver. Only when I set a website, cookies work fine in GC also. Now the url is `http://localhost/test/index.html`. Maybe has something to do with `Any scriptcan only read cookies that were set by a
web page from the same domain.`? Thanks anyway . Also check my question for another function of reading cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying variable `theCookie`:

```
var theCookie = "login=ScottPilgrimVStheWorld;";
```

We must do this because as stated in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), the template for a cookie is

`[cookie-name]=[cookie-name-val]; [Next is optional] expires=[expiry_date]`.

---

Also, I don't think you can just get the cookie directly like that. You have to create a function:

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
{
var c = ca[i].trim();
if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}
```

So you change your alert to something like this:

```
alert(getCookie("login"));
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Here is a fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/2/` . I edited the code based on the ansers here. This one does not even alert anything

Comment: My bad, I pasted JS in the CSS box. Here is the right fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kKfJK/6/`. Works even without your function. Also, your function works in IE, FF, still not in GC. I dont get it. It just alert an empty box.

Comment: Also, cookies are enabled on GC. The site is localhost, url is `file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache2.2/htd‌​ocs/test/index.html` Beats me!

Comment: I use Dreamweaver. Only when I set a website, cookies work fine in GC also. Now the url is http://localhost/test/index.html. Maybe has something to do with Any scriptcan only read cookies that were set by a web page from the same domain.? Thanks anyway . Also check my question for another function of reading cookies.